# Panel Data (Longitudinal) Analysis with SEM with continuous variables

Tags: chi-squared-test, panel-data, goodness-of-fit, structural-equation-modeling

I am estimating a SEM MIMIC model with 2 indicators, and 5 causes of a latent variable. I have a panel of around 170 countries for the period 1960-2018.

However, my chi-sq and general fit stats are terrible. I read that due to large samples this happens very often these goodness-of-fit stats.

Then, how could I assess my model? What statistical criteria should I use? OR at this point, I just need to consider that the coefficients of the causal variables are with the "right" sign and statistically significant?

Comment: Can you please explain SEM MIMIC?

Comment: it is a Multiple Indicators Multiple Causes Structural Equation Model

Comment: Are you using single-level SEM to fit this model or multilevel SEM? Single level SEM would seem highly problematic - you would need to have your model specified 58 times. Also, the poor fit could be due to the measurement model itself rather than the full MIMIC model. Do you have any more indicators you could work with?

Comment: I have other indicators but I am afraid they almost measure the same thing: corruption. I have indicators that measure public sector corruption, executive corruption, judicial corruption, legislative corruption, regime corruption, political corruption. Why would a single level SEM model is very complicated? Isn´t a MIMIC model  single-level by definition?